# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint error 1452

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with adding records to a table that I recently created and created a relationship with. I have a database called **"sandbox2"** and a table called **"country"** and another table called **"city"**.

The "country" table has columns:

```
"id" (primary key)
"countryname"
```

the "city" table has the columns:

```
"cityid"
"cityname"
"cid" -->Foreign key
```

When I try to add records to the city table, using the PHPmyadmin insert tool I recieve this error message:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sandbox2`.`city`, CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`)
>   REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**SQL Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `city` (`cityid`, `city`, `cid`) VALUES (NULL, 'johnson', '122')
```

I've looked at similar issues reported on this site and they mentioned checking the data types and ensure they are they same; they are both INT 11 characters. One thing I did notice that I don't know whether is relevant is that the default storage engine is set to My_ISAM, however my tables are setup with engine InnoDB (see picture). I havent been able to change the default engine to be InnoDB.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In you below query:

```
INSERT INTO `city` (`cityid`, `city`, `cid`) VALUES (NULL, 'johnson', '122')
```

The column `cityid` is a foreign key so it cann't be null. You have to give the value for this column that value should be present in country table's id column.

**Example:**

Country table data is:

```
id  | countryname
------------------
1   | US
2   | Uk
```

Then you can use only 1 or 2 as value for `cityid` column except other value it will give same error.

But as per your last image that you have added, the `cid` is foreign key and you are trying to insert value `122` in that column. Please ensure you have the same id in country table.

Comment: in the "city" table, "cid" is setup as foreign key. "cityid" is setup a primary key. "cityid" also is set as auto increment so shouldn't I be able to leave it null when I am inserting a new record? I initially had some data in the city table, but when I saw that there was no data populating in the country table I removed all records, so both tables have no data in it currently.

Comment: @Kevin If you have no data then in that case you have to insert some data in your country table first.

Comment: Ok looking back that would make sense that the Primary key table needs to have data populated in it before adding records to the 2nd (foreign key) table. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

In your description you said that cityid is your foreign key.  It should be cid.  Also, I'm assuming you have a country id with primary key 122?  Can you confirm?